# How to stop existing request execution to stop and just run fallback method in hystrix

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, circuit-breaker, fail-fast

In hystrix,I am using `execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds` this configuration to limit the response in some specific time else go for fallback method,But this setting is also executing the request which was invoked in the backend.Is it possible to stop that also?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "kill" an executing thread, you can implement some kind of interrupt logic, but it is not recommended in most cases.
If you post some code it will be easier to answer...